# How to render a template when paypal order is captured?

Tags: python, paypal

I am implementing a paypal server side payment button. I managed to create the order and capture it.

Now I would like to render a success template when the order is captured, but I don't know where, because here im returning the json response but how can i render a template when the payment is successful? How should this be done?

```
def capture(request, order_id, mail):
    if request.method == "POST":
        capture_order = OrdersCaptureRequest(order_id)
        environment = SandboxEnvironment(client_id=value, client_secret=value)
        client = PayPalHttpClient(environment)

        response = client.execute(capture_order)
        data = response.result.__dict__['_dict']
        letter = Letter.objects.filter(mail=mail).first()


        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'details': "invalid request"})
```

Comment: Assuming this function is called by your frontend code (the button) then I think instead of rendering a template, you'd need to do something in javascript to update the frontend UI accordingly.  Around where the [`alert` call is in this sample](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/#on-the-client).   How are you calling this function?

Comment: I have that in my html. Should I be rendering a page after the alert? @v25

Comment: `return render(request, 'letter/pagado.html', {
                              "name":name, "mail":mail
               })`

Comment: I should do something like this in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best front-end sample for a server-side integration: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This capture sample correctly handles the 3 cases of retrying, showing an error, and showing a success message.

For your implementation, the success case can be to manipulate the DOM to show whatever message / "template" you want to appear.

(You could even use `actions.redirect()` if you must, although redirects are a poor design choice and to be avoided as much as possible.)

Comment: What should be detected to manipulate the dom? Is it correct if i check that an alert popped up and then I show the success window? Otherwise I wont know that the payment was made

Comment: The alert is for demo purposes. Replace the alert with your own code to do what you want.  Manipulating the DOM refers to e.g. adding or unhiding a div or whatever it is that you want to do on success.